# PyCluster unable to install package

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, installation-package

This is the error I am getting when trying to install PyCluster. I am using python 2.7 with anaconda in spyder IDE and on windows.

```
Downloading/unpacking PyCluster

Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyCluster
URLs to search for versions for PyCluster:
* httpss://pypi.python.org/simple/PyCluster/
Getting page httpss://pypi.python.org/simple/PyCluster/
Analyzing links from page httpss://pypi.python.org/simple/pycluster/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyCluster

No distributions at all found for PyCluster

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anankuma\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\anankuma\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 256, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Users\anankuma\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1011, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\anankuma\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\index.py", line 157, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for PyCluster
```

Please suggest a workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here is](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pycluster) the package there is no source or binary available to download.

a module ([pyclustering](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyclustering)) with similar name.

The Python Package Index (**PYPI**) is a repository of software for the Python programming language.

One can download packages manually or using `pip install`

One can upload binary and source packages as well.

For example [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ModernGL/) package has a **source** and some binaries as well

**Python Wheel**s and **Python Egg**s are ease to install, mostly used on windows.

However manual install can be done using **MS Windows installer** files downloaded directly form **PYPI**

Comment: thanks for your reply...could you please elaborate how to use this page to install the package

Comment: `pip install module_name_without_version`

Comment: upgrade pip to be able to download wheels (binary formats as well)

Comment: do i have to download any binary file or something from the page you provided?

Comment: I have upgraded the pip to latest version

Comment: Thanks for your help..appreciated:)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar situation installing this `Pycluster` package

`pip` was trying to build the package because there were no official wheels
for Python 3.5 & windows.

Solved it by downloading an unofficial wheel from here:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycluster

There are many wheel files on this website.

Try different versions to see whichever works the best for you.

You can install the .whl file this way using `Anaconda Prompt` with the following code

```
pip install Pycluster-1.56-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

install with pip:

`pip3 install pyclustering`

it even works with Anaconda prompt

Comment: pyclustering and pycluster are different